# Erro de acesso a Model Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

Já conferi e todas as minhas chamadas estão corretas. O código rodava no Windows e transferi ele para o Ubuntu. Após a transferência dá esse erro:

> An Error Was Encountered
>
> Unable to locate the model you have specified: crudmodel

O model em questão (crudModel.php):

```php
<?php  if ( ! defined('BASEPATH')) exit('No direct script access allowed');

class CrudModel extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct()
    {       
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function add($tabela= NULL, $dados= NULL){
        if ($this->db->insert($tabela, $dados)){
            return TRUE;
        }
        else{
            return FALSE;
        }
    }

    public function delete($tabela= NULL, $dados= NULL){
        $this->db->where('id', $dados);
        if ($this->db->delete($tabela)){
            return TRUE;
        }
        else return FALSE;    
    }

    public function read($tabela= NULL){
        
        $result= $this->db->get($tabela);
        return $result;        
    }

    public function buscaDados($tabela= NULL, $dados= NULL){

        if ($tabela!= NULL && $dados!= NULL){
            $this->db->where('id', $dados);
            if ($this->db->update($tabela)){
                return TRUE;
            }
            else return FALSE;    
        }
        else return FALSE;    
    }

    public function update($tabela= NULL, $dados= NULL){

        if ($tabela!= NULL && $dados!= NULL){
            return $result= $this->db->get_where($tabela, $dados);
        }
        else return FALSE;        
    }
}
```

Pelo que vi, o problema está no autoload... mas não sei como acertar isso.

Autoload:

```php
$autoload['packages'] = array();
$autoload['libraries'] = array('form_validation', 'session', 'database', 'table', );
$autoload['helper'] = array('url', 'form', 'html', 'file', );
$autoload['model'] = array('crudModel', 'sessionModel', );
```

Exemplo de chamada do método do da classe model:

```php
$dados= $this->crudModel->buscaDados('usuario',$dados);
```

Comment: Filho, a gente precisa de dados, códigos pra analisar antes de dá uma resposta. Não sei quanto aos outros, mas eu faltei as cadeiras de adivinhação na faculdade (embora meus clientes também ignorem isso!). =D

Comment: Gostaria de saber se existe algum motivo que possa causar este erro... algo relacionado ao core do codeigniter, se precisasse de análise de código postava o mesmo na pergunta.

Comment: Cara, caminho! Ele tava no windows, e você mudou pra Linux. Inclusão de caminho real, barras (windows usa `\ `, já linux usa `/`)... como eu disse, são muitas as possibilidades. Poste o códigos, desde a inclusão até os caminhos padrões. Fica mais certeiro lhe ajudar.

Comment: Realmente falta informações

Comment: @Away, edite a sua pergunta e coloque a versão do CI.

Comment: Posta o autoload, mah! Posta onde tu inclui. Tudo, pra gente saber o que é!

Comment: @Away o nome da classe não deveria ser `Crudmodel` ao invés de `crudModel` ?

Comment: O nome da classe é CrudModel, seguindo a regra de ter a primeira letra do nome de classe em upper, agora o nome do arquivo e de suas chamadas tem a primeira letra em lower.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assim como você já tivesse esse problema.
Resolvi passando o nome do arquivo para lowercase. Utilizo a primeira letra do nome da classe em maiúscula, mas isso não interfere no carregamento da classe.

Exemplo:

Nome do arquivo: `usuario_model`;

Nome da classe: `Usuario_model`;

Isso está relacionado ao fato de que a classe CI_Loader do Codeigniter passa o nome da classe a ser carregada para lowercase antes de efetuar o carregamento. Assim, ao tentar carregar uma model você tanto pode declarar:

```
$this->load->model('usuario_model');
```

Ou

```
$this->load->model('Usuario_model');
```

Desde que o nome do arquivo em que a classe esta contida esteja em lowercase você não deverá ter problema.

Mas a utilização da classe obedece rigorosamente a sintaxe usada para carrega-la. Exemplo:

Se usar:

```
$this->load->model('Usuario_model');
```

Quando for utiliza-la deve usar:

```
$this->Usuario_model->get_by_id($id);
```

Se usar:

```
$this->load->model('usuario_model');
```

Quando for utiliza-la deve usar:

```
$this->usuario_model->get_by_id($id);
```

Comment: Alterei os nomes para lower e resolveu o problema. Obrigado

Answer (score 4):

Segundo esse [tópico](http://ellislab.com/forums/viewthread/114816/#581191), basta deixar o arquivo em lowercase

[TheFuzzy0ne](http://ellislab.com/forums/member/64725/):

> If nothing has changed then only difference will be the operating
>   system (one Linux and one Windows). Windows is case insensitive,
>   whereas Linux is not, so you need to ensure that the filenames for
>   your models are ALL lowercase, and that the class name is defined in
>   all lowercase (as it is with the file), but has the first letter
>   capitalised. Hopefully this will resolve the problem.

tradução

> Se nada mudou, então única diferença será o sistema operacional (um
>   Linux e um Windows). Windows é case insensitive, enquanto que o Linux
>   não é, por isso é necessário ter certeza que os nomes de arquivos
>   para seus modelos têm as letras minúsculas, e que o nome da
>   classe é definido em todas as letras minúsculas (como é com o
>   arquivo), mas tem a primeira letra maiúscula . Esperemos que isto irá
>   resolver o problema.

Comment: Conferi minhas nomeclaturas e todas estão certas, tanto como nos nomes de classe quanto nomeclatura dos arquivos.

Comment: @Away: de acordo com a informação fornecida, não basta conferir - tem que **alterar**. O nome do arquivo precisa ser todo em minúsculas. O nome da classe tem que ser todo em minúsculo - exceto a primeira letra. Exemplo: arquivo `crudmodel.php` para a classe `class Crudmodel`.

Comment: Na [documentação](http://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/models.html), diz: 'Os nomes de classe devem ter a primeira letra em maiúscula com o resto do nome em minúsculas. Certifique-se de sua classe estende a classe base Model.'